# Managing 1000+ user and each user's having 20,000+ rows for storing data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, web

I am using `php` and `mysql` to create a website. I am accepting at least 1000 users. Each user will have 10000+ objects(different user may have different objects) and each object will have at least five properties.So if create a table like

object_id | object_name | object_user_id | property_1|property_2|...|property_5

Then I will have 10 million rows. So this solution is not acceptable.

Shall I create a table for each user?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: 10 million rows isn't that many for serious database engines.  You're more likely to get useful help if you're more specific about the actual problem you're solving with this database.

Comment: One table with 10 million rows is more acceptable than having 1000+ tables. Make sure you do proper indexing on the second table.

Comment: You need 3 tables, users , objects , properties . Maybe more

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I am making a website for stores. So I need to store details of all available inventories which can be shown to customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your given description in question you may need three tables. 
1. `User` --> `userId`, `userName`, etc... 
2. `Object` --> `objectId`, `objectName`, etc... and `userId` (reference of `User`)
3. `Property` --> `propertyId`,`propertyName`, etc... and `objectId` (reference of `Object`)

Comment: object properties are different for different user ?

Comment: yes, it will be different. If possible give some example/sample data so that we can help you more. :)

Comment: I am making a website for stores. So I need to store all details(ex. Rate,Name,Quantity,Unit of Quantity etc.) of all inventories(ex. Pen,Books) available at each store. Finally we have to display this details to customers.

Comment: do you want to store it user wise different or the same for all the user?

Comment: then what is problem with given answer? it will work I think :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66968/discussion-between-sudesh-and-vishal-zanzrukia).

Comment: In your solution same object will have different object ids for different users. So we can not have object id as index. And we will have 20000 (objects) * 1000(users) = 20 million rows. So how is this solution reliable ?